# download zip with Zk framework

Tags: java, file, download, zip, zk

i'm using JDK 1.8, tomcat 7.0,ZK 8.0.2.2 and jsf-2.2.8 and  i have in my web-inf/lib the fowlling For the ZK framework jars :

> zcommon-8.0.2.2.jar
>
> zel-8.0.2.2.jar
>
> zk-8.0.2.2.jar
>
> zul-8.0.2.2.jar
>
> zweb-8.0.2.2.jar
>
> bsh-2.0b6.jar
>
> commons-codec-1.8.jar
>
> commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
>
> javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar
>
> slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
>
> slf4j-jdk14-1.7.5.jar

I create a zip file that contains 4 file With success.

Here is the function that creates a zip file 
    public class FileDownloadServer {

```
   public static void getZipFile(List<String> fileList, String fileZip, String sourcePath){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2014];
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileZip);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

        for(String file : fileList){
            ZipEntry ze= new ZipEntry(file);
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);
            System.out.println("avant");
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourcePath + File.separator + file);
            System.out.println("aprés");
             int len;
             while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
             }
             in.close();
        }
         zos.closeEntry();
         zos.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
 }


    }
```

And here the function for user :

```
    @ManagedBean
    public class testBean {

    private final static List<String> fileList=Arrays.asList("x.csv","z.csv","y.csv","t.csv");
    private final static String sourcePath="C:/output/";
    private final static String fileZip="C:/zip/batch.zip";  
    private final static String contentType="application/zip";

 public void download() throws IOException{
    FileDownloadServer.getZipFile(fileList, fileZip, sourcePath);

        File f = new File(fileZip);
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
         if(is.equals(null)){
             System.out.println("is is null");
         }else{
             System.out.println(" is not null");
         }
         if(contentType.equals(null)){
             System.out.println("contentType is null");
         }else{
             System.out.println("contentType not null");
         }
         if(f.getName()!=null){
             System.out.println("name " + f.getName());
         }else{
             System.out.println("flnm is null");
         }

        //For downloading zip file
        Filedownload.save(is, contentType, f.getName());
}
```

}
and i'm getting this exception `java.lang.NullPointerException` 
and the parameters of the function are not null i tried to display them before calling the function all is well:

```
mai 10, 2017 6:04:33 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
GRAVE: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.zkoss.zul.Filedownload.save(Filedownload.java:54)
at org.zkoss.zul.Filedownload.save(Filedownload.java:94)
at ma.controle.gestion.bean.batch.BatchExcelBean.uploadFile(BatchExcelBean.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:279)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload.broadcast(FileUpload.java:319)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:755)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.primefaces.barcelona.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:32)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I appreciate your help.

Thank's.

Comment: Is `Filedownload` a class you wrote?

Comment: @VGR No, it is a zk framework class to trigger the browser to download the file: https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Essential_Components/Filedownload

Comment: @Rodik, I checked the `Filedownload` code (version 8.0), and at line 54, it tries to get the current execution, which will only work inside an event listener thread. I have run into this problem as well. Are you calling `Filedownload.save()` in a worker thread?

Comment: @MalteHartwig sorry for being late, i'm calling Filedownload.save() in a worker thread.

After reading the documentation of JSF 2 I was able to write a function
Which executed my need for the moment without appealing to ZK framework.

i will put it if maybe will be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to wrap it up for future readers: The line in `Filedownload.save()` that fails tries to retrieve the current `Execution`, which will fail as you are calling `save()` in a worker thread (i.e. a thread that has no access to the `Desktop`).

Read this link for more information on how to access the desktop/execution from a worker thread with the help of `Executions.activate(Desktop)`:
https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2015/January/Simplify_Long_Operation_Handlings#Long_Operations_made_simple